# How to know where the variable was initialized or last modified

Tags: php

Is there any way in PHP to know where a variable was initialized or assigned the value for first time OR where it was last modified?

I think it should be possible to know this because PHP gives some such hint in errors. Like: `Can not redeclare abc() (previously declared in /path/to/file.php)`

**EDIT:**
I need this because:

```
function abc() {
   global $page; //this should be int.
   if($page == 2) { ... }
}
```

But when this function is run; I get error `Can not convert object into int`. This is because some where in my code $page is overriden by any object. I need to find that place where it was modified. Or I'll have to dig through entire code.

Comment: Can you tell us why you need that?

Comment: Tracking where a function declaration can be found and where a variable was modified are two different things. The latter would require keeping a history log of the entire state of the program, which is simply prohibitively expensive.

Comment: you can use `isset` see http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: what? what do you mean `variable was initialized`? your error suggests of functions being declared again

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this unless you have some good reason. The quickest thing I can guess is to create an array of variables and then check against that array to see if something is declared or not or log any changes.

Comment: BTW, that's another good argument for limiting *variable scope* as much as possible. If you have variables which are so pervasive throughout your app that you can't even figure out where their value was last modified, your code is simply unmaintainable.

Comment: `global` usage isn't recommended. Why don't you pass the `$page` variable as a parameter of your function?

Comment: As you told u got error....`Can not redeclare abc() (previously declared in /path/to/file.php)`. so you can find out from error.

Comment: Yup, thanks for proving again why `global` is such a bad idea... I'm afraid you *will* have to dig through all your code. That's why you shouldn't write such code in the first place. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out which object is being assigned to your $page variable using the native php function get_class() :

```
get_class($page);
```

You would normally want to debug this using a unit test where you would test that the variable $page is numeric.

If you just want to debug on-screen try:

```
if(is_object($page)){
     die(get_class($page));
    }
```

or via an exception:

```
if(is_object($page)){
 throw new Exception('$page must be numeric object given of type : '.get_class($page));
}
```

This will help you find which object is being assigned to your variable and just point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know where a variable was defined then you are out of luck; there is no way to find that out, other than actually looking through your code and finding it.

Your problem seems to be that you are allowing a variable into a function (using `global`). Because the variable is defined outside the function it can be modified at any time. If you want to always know what the variable contains then you should pass it as an argument instead:

```
$page = 2;
function abc($page) {
   if($page == 2) { ... }
}
$test = abc($page);
```

If you want to make sure that the value of the variable is a number then you can find that out by simply validating the argument (or the `global` variable, for that matter):

```
if (is_int($page) or ctype_digit($page)) {
    echo 'The $page variable is a number';
} else {
    echo 'The $page variable is NOT a number';
}
```

Comment: I believe the function redeclaration was nowhere part of the question. It was just an example for PHP "tracking information".

Comment: @deceze Yeah, you are right. I removed the part about functions. Thank you.